# Remove elements from Array Perl

Tags: perl

How to remove matching elements from the array? Let say I have array `@A [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]` and now I have remove element 2 and 3 so I should see `@A [ 1, 4, 4, 4, 5]` only in the array.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3A%3AUniq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grep` to filter out elements you don't want:

```
my @A    = (1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5);
my @newA = grep { $_ != 2 } @A; 
# @newA has elements (1,3,4,4,4,5)
```

Comment: Can I store the modified output in the same array like @A = grep {$_ !=2 } @A ?